# How make a get request with an ForeignKey atribute in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Basically i want to make a get method that when filled with person_id, list all the addresses of that person in json format. Already tried many other methods but none came close

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

# Create your models here.

class Address(models.Model):
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    person_id = models.ForeignKey('Person', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="addresses")

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from data.views import PersonViewSet, AddressViewSet
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'person', PersonViewSet, base_name='person')
router.register(r'address', AddressViewSet, base_name = 'address')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Example:
    url: http://localhost:8000/address
    method: GET
    param: person_id: 0001

This request expect a list like that
    {
        "id": 5,
        "zipcode": "111",
        "state": "FL",
        "city": "Miami",
        "street": "12",
        "number": 111,
        "person_id": 1
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a custom manager for filtering using GET parameters.

As an example,

```
class AddressQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def filter_by_request_params(self, request):

        person_str = request.GET.get('person', None)

        if person_str:
            self = self.filter(person_id=int(person_str.strip()))

        return self
```

In your models,

```
class Address(models.Model):
    ......
    ......

    objects = AddressQuerySet.as_manager()
```

In your viewsets,

```
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ......

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = self.queryset.filter_by_request_params(request)
        return super(AddressViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now you can add more filters in the `QuerySet()` method and use it as GET parameters, like http://127.0.0.1:8000/address/?person=1

Comment: i think you need update your answer `person` --> `person_id` by OP model

Comment: AddressQuerySet to AddressManager too, thank you very much man, you helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

you can use [detail_route](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions)

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route

class PersonViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
# You code here

    @detail_route(methods=['get'], )
    def addresses(self, request, pk):
        """
        Show person address.
        """
        person = self.get_object()
        serializer = AddressSerializer(person.addresses, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

now you can get list of the person addresses by 
`http://localhost:8000/person/1/addresses`